# Numpy - Multiply each element of a matrix with the element of another matrix at the same position

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'd like to multiply each element of a 3D matrix with the element of a same-sized matrix at the same position.

In 2D it'd look like:

[image]

Is there any clean solution with numpy other than for loops ?

EDIT:
This matrix operation is named "Hadamard product"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply them. `numpy` supports matrix operations.

```
x = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3)
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

```
print(x*x)
```

All elements will be multiplied by the respective number.

```
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [16, 25, 36],
       [49, 64, 81]])
```

Comment: Good answer, though the example provided doesn't necessarily demonstrate the element-wise nature of the result.

Comment: you're right, i changed the example.

Comment: This would do matrix multiplication, not element wise multiplication like the OP is asking

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `*` to to element-wise multiplication with numpy arrays.

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

print(a*b)
```

Will give you

```
[[ 1  4]
 [ 9 16]]
```

Comment: This is a good clear answer.